# Invalidate or clear certain entity types from breeze.js cache

Tags: breeze

Given a fairly standard scenario in an application, of having a list of entities that can be added/edited/deleted etc.  When I first load the page, I query the entites with breeze.  All good.  If I edit an entity, breeze sees this and the entity is saved AND updated in the cache, so when I return to the page with the list, the item shows any relevant changes.  If I delete an entity, breeze will again save that change AND update it's cache so the entity no longer appears when I return to the list page and requery the data (locally from the cache I should point out).

However, if I add a new entity, it does not appear on the list page (assuming it satisfies the requirements of the query).  I'm guessing that breeze is caching the results of a query specific to that query, rather than actually querying the cache (does that make sense)?

Assuming that is the case, is there a way of telling breeze to remove or invalidate cache items relating to a specific entity type, as opposed to clearing the cache completely?  I can always avoid querying the cache and go directly to the server, but that seems a waste when I know breeze has the newly created entity in the cache, it just isn't showing it to me.

I use a single method for a lot of my queries, so it may just be the way I'm handling the local querying in that method, therefore I have included it below, in case that is the cause.

```
var defaultQuery = function (observable, resourceName, orderby, where, expand, forceRemote, localEntityName, localCountThreshold, page, count) {
            var query = EntityQuery.from(resourceName);
            if (orderby) {
                query = query.orderBy(orderby);

                if (page) {
                    query = query.skip(pageSize * (page()));
                    query = query.take(pageSize);
                    query = query.inlineCount();
                }
            }
            if (where)
                query = query.where(where);
            if (expand)
                query = query.expand(expand);

            if (!forceRemote) {
                if (localEntityName) {
                    query = query.toType(localEntityName);
                }
                var localResult = manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
                if (localCountThreshold) {
                    if (localResult.length > localCountThreshold) {
                        observable(localResult);
                        return Q.resolve();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (localResult.length > 0) {
                        observable(localResult);
                        return Q.resolve();
                    }
                }
            }

            return query.using(manager)
                .execute()
                .then(function (data) {
                    if (observable) {
                        observable(data.results);
                    }
                    if (count) {
                        count(data.inlineCount);
                    }
                    var logMsg = 'Retrieved ' + resourceName + ' from remote data source with order by {' + orderby + '}, where clause {' + where + '} and expand properties {' + expand + '}';
                    if (page)
                        logMsg += ' for page {' + page() + '} with total record count {' + count() + '}';
                    log(logMsg, data, true);
                })
                .fail(queryFailed);
        };
```

Usually in questions like this, I have just misunderstood some aspect of how breeze works, so if anyone can correct me, I'd be very appreciative.

Thanks!

---

**Update**

I have included the flow of actions step by step to show in more detail what I meant.

1. Execute Query for all objects
2. Query is executed locally first, returns nothing as no cache data exists.
3. Query is then executed against the database - returns [A,B,C]
4. Edit A - rename to AA - call saveChanges()
5. Execute same query for all objects
6. Query is executed locally first, returns [AA,B,C]
7. Query skips executing against database as results have been found from cache.
8. Delete B (setDeleted()) - call saveChanges()
9. Execute same query for all objects
10. Query is executed locally first, returns [AA,C]
11. Query skips executing against database as results have been found from cache.
12. Create new entity - set name to D - call saveChanges()
13. Execute same query for all objects
14. Query is executed locally first, returns [AA,C] (does not include new D object!)

The point I'm trying to discover is that local queries return changes saved for edits and deletes, but not for add operations.  I could remove entities from the cache by using setDetached as Jay suggested, but I would need to do that for all entities of a specific type one-by-one.  That could be a big process.

---

**Update again**

It appears the behaviour I saw was the result of some mistake by myself.  Having double and triple checked everything as a result of Jay's assertion that the results should be there (see below), the 'added' objects are now appearing, but I honestly can't explain what I did to prevent them in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be clear, Breeze updates the cache when you edit an entity, it does NOT save that entity until you call *EntityManager.saveChanges()*. So until you call "*saveChanges*" the cache and your database will be in different states.

What you might be seeing is the result of the idea that when you requery an entity that has already been changed in the EntityManager, the action of merging the server side data with the client side cache is controlled by the *EntityQuery.queryOptions.mergeStrategy*.  By default, an EntityQuery has a MergeStrategy of *PreserveChanges* which means that a server side result will NOT overwrite any "modified" records in the cache.

Per the later part of your post, you can remove any entity from the local cache simply by calling the entity's "entityAspect.setDetached" method.

Comment: Apologies, I should have been clearer.  I meant that breeze saves the changes and updates the cache, when I call savechanges.  I have updated the question to show the example flow...  hopefully that makes it clearer.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see the issue from your example code. But local queries DO run against the cache exactly as you would expect, this means that "added" entities will get picked up.  If you don't see them then my guess is that you've created the added entities but haven't yet "added" or "attached" them to the entityManager. See EntityManager.addEntity/EntityManager.attachEntity.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the comment before I updated the main question.  Ok so "added" entities should show up.  So something about my process of creating entities may be off.  I'll quickly check and come back.

Comment: So I have no idea what I was doing, but it behaves exactly as you described now :D  Honestly I experienced exactly the behaviour I described, hence the fact I took the time to try and describe it in full because I couldn't see why I wasn't seeing the 'added' entities.  Apologies and thank you for taking the time to reply.  This has raised another interesting question of how to handle the inlinecount when querying locally but I'll start digging into that and see what I can find.

Comment: InlineCount for local queries is not supported. ( You will basically need to query twice); once normally and once with any skip/take removed. The reason we don't support it locally is that the answer will always be "wrong" unless you've loaded "all" of the entities for a given resource name, which is probably a very bad practice. Remember that the local cache has no idea about any entities that have not already been queried.

Comment: I can understand why the inlineCount is not supported entirely.  In my case I am not querying all the entities, but I am getting the count of all entities with the initial page.  Therefore in one sense, if I add or delete from that entity set, the inlineCount could be 'tracked' as I know what I have done to the overall entity set.  However obviously this does not handle multiuser scenarios, and would almost certainly lead to incorrect results.  I suspect the 'benefit' I was looking for with querying locally just isn't really available in a normal 'crud; scenario, but breeze is still awesome!

Comment: Local queries are great for avoiding having to go back to the database or when you are in an offline scenario.  But there are limitations... :)

Comment: I know this is a bit of an older question, but just to be clear: calling `entityAspect.setDetached()` on an entity will simply evict it from the local cache, and _not_ delete it from the server, correct? Is this the advised way of freeing up space in the local storage if we're bumping up against the storage limit?

Comment: Yes. Or on a more global level you can also call EntityManager.Clear which we detach all of the entities within an EntityManager.